# how to call parameterized constructor from default constructor?

Tags: java, constructor

I want to call parameterized constructor from default constructor inside a public java class.

Can I achieve it?

```
public Rectangle()
{
Rectangle(10.5f,2.5f)     //this not working
}
public Rectangle(float length, float breadth)
{
code...
}
```

Comment: `this(10.5f, 2.5f)`.

Comment: also, don't forget the closing ;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `this` keyword.

This should do the trick:

```
public Rectangle() {
    this(10.5f, 2.5f);
}

public Rectangle(float length, float breadth) {
    //code..
}
```